# How to add Notes to a particular slide in a ppt

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

Currently I have a task that insert custom note to a particular slide of a ppt using openxml. from referencing this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278319.aspx). I am trying to add note to a slide but I am getting the following Error.

```
Error Message :
     Only one instance of the type is allowed for this parent.
Stack Trace:
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.InitPart[T](T newPart, String contentType, String id)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.InitPart[T](T newPart, String contentType)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddNewPartInternal[T]()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddNewPart[T]()
   at AddNoteToPPT.Program.AddNote(String docName, Int32 index) in d:\Projects\Task\Project\AddNoteToPPT\AddNoteToPPT\Program.cs:line 45
```

Here is my working copy

```
using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, true))
{
    // Get the relationship ID of the first slide.
    PresentationPart part = ppt.PresentationPart;
    OpenXmlElementList slideIds = part.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;

    string relId = (slideIds[index] as SlideId).RelationshipId;

    // Get the slide part from the relationship ID.
    SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)part.GetPartById(relId);

    // Build a StringBuilder object.
    StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();

    // Get the inner text of the slide:
    IEnumerable<A.Text> texts = slide.Slide.Descendants<A.Text>();

    NotesSlidePart notesSlidePart1 = slide.AddNewPart<NotesSlidePart>();
    NotesSlide notesSlide = new NotesSlide(
    new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree(
      new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
      new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
      new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
      new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
      new GroupShapeProperties(new TransformGroup()),
      new P.Shape(
      new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
        new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "" },
        new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
        new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape())),
      new P.ShapeProperties(),
      new P.TextBody(
        new BodyProperties(),
        new ListStyle(),
        new Paragraph(new EndParagraphRunProperties()))))),
    new ColorMapOverride(new MasterColorMapping()));
    notesSlidePart1.NotesSlide = notesSlide;
}
```

using this code I am able to get the content of existing Note.

```
slide.NotesSlidePart.SlidePart.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code works for me but after adding or appending note to a slide if you decorate the text of note then in the next reading it will give error
Below code works for me but after adding or appending note to a slide if you decorate the text of note then in the next reading it will give error

```
string relId = "rId" + (index + 1);
using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, false))
{
    PresentationPart part = ppt.PresentationPart;
    OpenXmlElementList slideIds = part.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;

    relId = (slideIds[index] as SlideId).RelationshipId;
}
using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, true))
{

    PresentationPart presentationPart1 = ppt.PresentationPart;
    SlidePart slidePart2 = (SlidePart)presentationPart1.GetPartById(relId);
    NotesSlidePart notesSlidePart1;
    string existingSlideNote = "";

    if (slidePart2.NotesSlidePart != null)
    { 
        //Appened new note to existing note.
        existingSlideNote = slidePart2.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText + "\n";
        var val = (NotesSlidePart)slidePart2.GetPartById(relId);
        notesSlidePart1 = slidePart2.AddPart<NotesSlidePart>(val, relId);
    }
    else
    {  
        //Add a new noteto a slide.                      
        notesSlidePart1 = slidePart2.AddNewPart<NotesSlidePart>(relId);
    }

    NotesSlide notesSlide = new NotesSlide(
        new CommonSlideData(new ShapeTree(
          new P.NonVisualGroupShapeProperties(
            new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)1U, Name = "" },
            new P.NonVisualGroupShapeDrawingProperties(),
            new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties()),
            new GroupShapeProperties(new A.TransformGroup()),
            new P.Shape(
                new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                    new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)2U, Name = "Slide Image Placeholder 1" },
                    new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new A.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true, NoRotation = true, NoChangeAspect = true }),
                    new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.SlideImage })),
                new P.ShapeProperties()),
            new P.Shape(
                new P.NonVisualShapeProperties(
                    new P.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)3U, Name = "Notes Placeholder 2" },
                    new P.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties(new A.ShapeLocks() { NoGrouping = true }),
                    new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties(new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.Body, Index = (UInt32Value)1U })),
                new P.ShapeProperties(),
                new P.TextBody(
                    new A.BodyProperties(),
                    new A.ListStyle(),
                    new A.Paragraph(
                        new A.Run(
                            new A.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false },
                            new A.Text() { Text = existingSlideNote + "Value Updated" }),
                        new A.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false }))
                    ))),
        new ColorMapOverride(new A.MasterColorMapping()));

    notesSlidePart1.NotesSlide = notesSlide;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer below code which will work even if you decorate the text of note after updating or appending note to a slide.

```
if (slidePart2.NotesSlidePart != null)
{
    //Appened new note to existing note.
      existingSlideNote =         slidePart2.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.InnerText + "\n";
    var val = slidePart2.NotesSlidePart;
    notesSlidePart1 = slidePart2.AddPart<NotesSlidePart>(val);
}
else
{  
    //Add a new noteto a slide.                      
    notesSlidePart1 = slidePart2.AddNewPart<NotesSlidePart>(relId);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this code works. But one problem occurs with printing. If you try to print the notes (select notespages - slides with notes) only the notes are printed. Not the slides. Expected behavior is print slide content and below the notes. Somebody get this working?